# Undefined value in asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting an undefined value in my asynchronous method which looks for a value in a array and return the object that has the particular value. The undefined value is in the find method

`this.calculatorResult` looks like this but is call from a web service:

```
  [
    {
       "newCalculatedInstallmentsNo": "50",
       "newContractEndDate": "20250701",
       "newResidual": "0",
       "newInstalment": "4071.91",
       "newTerm": "52",
       "outBalanceAvaf": null,
       "restructureType": "term"
    },
    {
       "newCalculatedInstallmentsNo": "52",
       "newContractEndDate": "20250901",
       "newResidual": "0",
       "newInstalment": "3939.93",
       "newTerm": "54",
       "outBalanceAvaf": null,
       "restructureType": "instalment"
    }
  ]


//reduceoptionRadio value is got from a model
this.loanAdjustmentDetailsFormData = this.avafService.getAvafFormData();
this.reduceoptionRadio = this.loanAdjustmentDetailsFormData.reduceoptionRadio;

calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment() {
        console.log(this.reduceoptionRadio); //instalment
        this.progressSpinnerService.startLoading();
        this.avafService.CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustment({accountNumber: this.accountNumber, advanceAmount: '5000'}).subscribe((resp)=>{
          this.progressSpinnerService.stopLoading();
          //Get relevant values from calculator service
          this.confirmData = resp.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment.calculatorResults;
          Object.keys(this.confirmData).forEach((key)=>{ const value = this.confirmData[key];
          this.calculatorResult = [value];
          console.log(this.calculatorResult);
          });
          //return object that has the matching restructure type
          this.calculateFormData = this.calculatorResult.find( el => el.restructureType === this.reduceoptionRadio );
          console.log(this.calculateFormData); //undefined
        })
 }
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: can you please console -> `this.reduceoptionRadio`

Comment: @DhavalDarji I get the value successfully if I add the console at the top of the `calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment` function. I will edit above to show.

Comment: You are trying to compare two objects with `===`. JavaScript will tell you if the objects have the same **reference**, but you are probably looking for a deep comparison of the properties.

Comment: @JSONDerulo Even if I stringify the comparison like this I get undefined

`this.calculateFormData = this.calculatorResult.find( el => JSON.stringify(el.restructureType) === JSON.stringify(this.loanAdjustmentDetailsFormData.reduceoptionRadio));`

Comment: Are you getting array of array compulsory ? Like will you get only `[[{},{}]]` or will you also get like this `[[{},{}],[{},{}]]` ? Please answer

Comment: @DhavalDarji I will only get [{},{}]

Comment: Okay but as per your question eg. it looks like multi-dimensional array `[[{},{}]]`

Comment: @DhavalDarji yes sorry, just updated it. It's just one array

Comment: Put those two lines of finding from array, into API callback function after  `console.log(this.calculatorResult)`,

Comment: What is 
`console.log(typeof this.reduceoptionRadio)`
`console.log(typeof this.calculatorResult[0].restructureType)` 
Try and tell me

Comment: @DhavalDarji Actually you found the issue. I was adding the array into another array array here `this.calculatorResult = [value];`. this was the issue. I removed the [] around the value and it worked. You can add the answer and I'll mark as correct

Comment: @skydev Yeah boy, keep learning, Keep growing.

Answer (score -3):

### **you must call calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment() in the ngOnit() method then this would be work**

```js
   
  ngOnInit() {
  this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment();}
this.loanAdjustmentDetailsFormData = this.avafService.getAvafFormData();
this.reduceoptionRadio = this.loanAdjustmentDetailsFormData.reduceoptionRadio;

calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment() {
        console.log(this.reduceoptionRadio); //instalment
        this.progressSpinnerService.startLoading();
        this.avafService.CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustment({accountNumber: this.accountNumber, advanceAmount: '5000'}).subscribe((resp)=>{
          this.progressSpinnerService.stopLoading();
          //Get relevant values from calculator service
          this.confirmData = resp.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment.calculatorResults;
          Object.keys(this.confirmData).forEach((key)=>{ const value = this.confirmData[key];
          this.calculatorResult = [value];
          console.log(this.calculatorResult);
          });
          //return object that has the matching restructure type
          this.calculateFormData = this.calculatorResult.find( el => el.restructureType === this.reduceoptionRadio );
          console.log(this.calculateFormData); //undefined
        })
 }
```

---

Comment: Now it will just be calling the same method twice

Comment: how we call calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment() method without call in ngOninIt() method.if we do not call this method in ngOninIt() then calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment() method not run